# Subset by value of next row

Tags: r

I'm looking to subset rows by the value of the next row for one column.

`df <- data.frame(t = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 b = c(1,2,1,0,1,0,1,2))`

So I want to subset `df` and get the rows where `b == 2` following any row where `b == 1`. So subset should return 2 rows (where t=1 and t=7)

I tried using `which` and `lag` from dplyr, as mentioned in other answers, but I couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the next value with `lead`, create a condition to check whether it is equal to 2 and the current value is 1 and use that expression in the `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(b == 1, lead(b)==2)
#  t b
#1 1 1
#2 7 1
```

---

Or use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df, c(b[-1] == 2, FALSE) & b == 1)
```